# Xfig: export a grid and a dot inside a coloured rectangle

Tags: graphics, diagrams, technical-drawing, xfig

I have this `1D_BZ_modif.fig` file:

```
#FIG 3.2  Produced by xfig version 3.2.5c
Landscape
Center
Metric
A4
100.00
Single
-2
1200 2
1 3 0 1 0 0 50 -1 20 0.000 1 0.0000 0 6975 142 142 0 6975 142 6975
1 3 0 1 0 0 50 -1 20 0.000 1 0.0000 1414 6975 142 142 1414 6975 1556 6975
1 3 0 1 0 0 50 -1 20 0.000 1 0.0000 2121 6975 142 142 2121 6975 2263 6975
1 3 0 1 0 0 50 -1 20 0.000 1 0.0000 2827 6975 142 142 2827 6975 2969 6975
1 3 0 1 0 0 50 -1 20 0.000 1 0.0000 3534 6975 142 142 3534 6975 3676 6975
1 3 0 1 0 0 50 -1 20 0.000 1 0.0000 4241 6975 142 142 4241 6975 4383 6975
1 3 0 1 0 0 100 -1 20 0.000 1 0.0000 675 6975 142 142 675 6975 817 6975
2 2 0 1 0 30 50 -1 20 0.000 0 0 -1 0 0 5
         360 6615 1067 6615 1067 7322 360 7322 360 6615
3 2 1 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 4.000 0 1 1 2
        13 0 1.00 60.00 120.00
        13 0 1.00 60.00 120.00
         360 7515 1080 7515
         0.000 0.000
3 2 0 5 4 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 1 0 2
        1 1 6.00 60.00 120.00
         2827 6975 3534 6975
         0.000 0.000
3 2 0 2 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 0 2
         -1080 6975 13950 6975
         0.000 0.000
4 0 0 50 -1 0 20 0.0000 6 285 450 495 7875 $b$\001
4 0 0 50 -1 0 20 0.0000 6 315 4005 2925 7425 $\\textcolor{red}{\\mathbf{b}}$\001
```

in which there is:

1) Latex fonts

2) A grid

3) A chain of black dots, one of them is in a pink shaded rectangle:

In order to compile all this information in a single `eps` output, according to the official documentation, the `Combined PS/Latex` option has to be used in the `Export` menu:

1) Open the xfig file: `xfig 1D_BZ_modif.fig`

2) `File` /  `Export`  / `Combined PS/LaTeX (both parts)` / `Export all layers` / `Export`. This generates a `1D_BZ_modif.pstex_t` file.

3) Create a file called `1D_BZ_modif.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %(note: you might not might not need to do this)
\setlength{\textwidth}{100cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{100cm}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\input{1D_BZ_modif.pstex_t}
\end{document}
```

4) Now make:

```
latex 1D_BZ_modif.tex
dvips -E 1D_BZ_modif.dvi  -o 1D_BZ_modif.eps
```

This generates the following `1D_BZ_modif.eps` file:

[image]

in which:

1) The grid does not appear

2) The black dot under the shaded pink rectangle also does not appear.

How could I make both that grid and black dot to appear in a final `eps` ?

Comment: It's probably faster to re-draw it with tikz.... I am an unconditional of `xfig`, but it's not the most up-to-date sw around here....

Answer (score 2):

1) A grid is not stored in a fig-file, but must be given when exporting the
figure. In the export dialog, `File / Export / Combined PS/LaTeX`,
the `Grid/Major` field serves this purpose.

2) Since the black bullet is located at a greater depth than the pink rectangle,
I understand that the OP asks the bullet to be drawn as if the pink rectangle
were partially transparent. There are two possibilities:

A) Fake transparency, by painting the black dot as a circle with line width
zero, filled with the same pink color as the rectangle, but shaded towards
black (and located at a lesser depth than the pink rectangle). For instance,
replace the first 9 numbers of the 7th line below `1200 2`, i.e.,
`1 3 0 1 0 0 100 -1 20` by `1 3 0 0 0 30 40 -1 16`.

Export to Combined PS/LaTeX using directly fig2dev, which is the
frontend program that is called by xfig when exporting graphics. Here, a grid of 1 cm is demanded,

```
fig2dev -L pstex -G10mm 1D_BZ_modif.fig A.pstex
fig2dev -L pstex_t -p A.pstex 1D_BZ_modif.fig A.pstex_t
```

replace `1D_BZ_modif.pstex_t` in the file `1D_BZ_modif.tex` by `A.pstex_t` and
produce the eps,

```
latex 1D_BZ_modif.tex
dvips -E 1D_BZ_modif.dvi -o 1D_BZ_modif.eps
```

[image]

B) For a better transparency effect, Xfig version >= 3.2.6 can export to tikz.
The drawing specification of the rectangle in the tikz file would have to be
manually edited by adding, e.g., `opacity=0.5`,

```
fig2dev -L tikz -G10mm -P 1D_BZ_modif.fig B.tex
edit B.tex
pdftex B.tex
```

The `-P` option creates a stand-alone tex file, instead of a tikz-file to be
\input into a tex file, after \usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}.
The above creates B.pdf, which must be converted to eps.
`latex B.tex; dvips B.dvi` produces an image that lacks the transparency effect.
[image]